# How to fill datasource of datagridview in vb .net with object generic dictionary (see image)

Tags: .net, vb.net

[image]
I try to use the structure in the picture to fill a datagridview or simular to show the data. I have no idea how to do this. The instructions (in c#) tells me to use: 
var transHistory = btceApi.GetTransHistory();
As far as I understand it returns list() as dictionary( of integer, transaction) 
(public class transhistory)

I translated it like this: Dim trnh As object  = BtceApi.GetTransHistory(count:=20)
which actually returns 20 records, see image.
But how to bind(?) and show the data from then on?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: Are you willing to learn how to do it manually with code, or do you just want a simple binding solution?

Comment: i would like to know the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the datagrid view (if it is not already created)

```
Private data_grid As new DataGridView()
```

Then set up its properties (some of these are optional)

```
With data_grid
    .Name = "data_grid"
    .Location = New Point(0,0)
    .Parent = Me
    .Width = 600
    .Height = 0 ' I set this to 0 here because I change it later
End With
```

In case you want to clear the grid you can use this:

```
' Clear everything out of the data grid
' -------------------------------------
  With data_grid
       While .RowCount > 0
         .Rows.Clear()
       End While
       While .ColumnCount > 0
         .Columns.Clear()
       End While
  End With
```

Add the columns to the grid like this:

```
' Add the column headers to the columns
' -------------------------------------
  Dim col_0 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
   col_0.Name = "key"
   data_grid.Columns.Add(col_0)

   Dim col_1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
   col_1.Name = "Name"
   col_1.FillWeight = 100
   col_1.ReadOnly = True 'optional
   data_grid.Columns.Add(col_1)

   Dim col_2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
   col_2.Name = "Address"
   col_2.FillWeight = 70
   col_2.ReadOnly = True 'optional
   data_grid.Columns.Add(col_2)
```

Now that you have added the columns, you need to populate them

First you need to add all of the rows that you will use. So this is the number of records in your set.

```
data_grid.Rows.Add(grid_data_array.Count()) ' in your case grid_data_array is your collection
```

Then add the data to the columns like this:

```
' Add the data to the columns
' ---------------------------
  For r As Integer = 0 To grid_data_array.Count() - 1
    data_grid.Item(0, r).Value = grid_data_array(r)(0) ' key 
    data_grid.Item(1, r).Value = grid_data_array(r)(1) ' name
    data_grid.Item(2, r).Value = grid_data_array(r)(2) ' address
  Next
```

My array has two dimensions, yours may have only one.

Now, I set up the final parameters. Some of these are optional. I set the height of my grid to 400 pixels. If it goes above that, then I add scrollbars and keep it at 400. If it is less, then no scrollbars. Also I set col. 0 to hidden since I don't want people to see the key of the row.

```
With data_grid
     .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
     .RowHeadersVisible = False ' remove the first column of headers
     .AllowUserToAddRows = False ' remove the last row from the list that shows up when adding the vertical scrollbar
     .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
     .AllowUserToOrderColumns = True
     .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
     .MultiSelect = False
     .AllowUserToResizeRows = False
     .Columns(0).Visible = False 'hide the (key) column

      ' if there are more rows than space available, then add a scoll bar
      ' -----------------------------------------------------------------
        If ((data_grid.RowCount * 24) + 25) > Me.Height - 400 Then
             .ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
             data_grid.Height = Me.Height - 400
        Else
      ' just set the height to equal the height of the rows with no scroll bar
      ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            .Height = (.RowCount * 24) + 25
            .ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None
        End If
End With
```

- The default height of a row is 24 pixels and the default height of the header row is 25 pixels. That's why I use those numbers in calculating the size of the grid.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried. I encounter an error in
For r As Integer = 0 To trnh.Count - 1
> public member Count for type TransHistory not found.

Comment: Can you iterate through your 20 records and put them into an array?

Comment: trnh needs to be a collection. It could be an array or arraylist or just a list, but it needs a count.

Comment: I hoped it could be done in a quicker, simpler way, in one statement but I think I will do it like this. Would that be the best way?
       For Each transaction In trnh.List

            With transaction
                Dim v1 As Integer = .Key
                Dim v2 As Transaction = .Value
                ...= v2.amount
                ...= v2.currency etc etc
            End With
        Next

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by what would be the best way. But you simply need to iterate through your collection the best way you can (or know how) and put the values into the columns and rows.